# How to suppress the numbers in \thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I was wondering if anyone could help me? I have an issue with \thebibliography, I would like to suppress the numbers and cannot work out how. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

xyz \cite{Ackerman}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Ackerman} Ackerman, E. (2017) Why the English Premier League Should Have Playoffs.  Balls.ie. Available at: https://www.balls.ie/football/premier-league-playoffs-364654 

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you included a lot of unrelated packages, but no document class so no one can run your example.

Comment: Updated, thanks @DavidCarlisle. I just wasn't sure if any of these packages were conflicting :)

Comment: It is easy for you to check that, just delete them and check that the code you are posting demonstrates the problem.

Comment: your example doesn'r have any `\cite` which would normally generate a number (so removing numbers from the list being confusing) if you don't have `\cite` you don't really need thebibliography at all. You could just use an itemize or even a paragraph.

Comment: Is that better ? :) Apologies, I am very inexperienced

Comment: The example is better but now the question isn't clear. The `\cite` makes [1] so requires the [1] in the bibliography to make sense.  Or do you want an author-year citation style and change both the citation and the list or ....

Comment: If you want to delete the numeric labels in the formatted bibliography, how do you want the citation call-outs to look like? Do you want to use authoryear-style citation call-outs instead of numeric citation call-outs?

Comment: Yeah, I would like the author-year citation if possible too?

Comment: Please see if the following is helpful:https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly, you (a) will be building the formatted bibliography entirely by hand *and* (b) wish to create authoryear-style citation call-outs rather than numeric citation call-outs.

If this understanding is correct, I suggest you (a) load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `authoryear` and (b) provide more citation-related information in the optional argument of `\bibitem`. Inside the optional argument, list the author(s) and then the publication year, with the publication year encased in parentheses, and *no space* between the author name(s) and the `(year)`.

Ideally, though, you'd decide to learn how to use BibTeX and select a suitable bibliography style, so that you don't have to do all this stuff by hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
textual citation: \citet{Ackerman}

parenthetic citation: \citep{Ackerman}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Ackerman(2017)]{Ackerman} Ackerman, E. (2017) Why the English Premier League Should Have Playoffs.  Balls.ie. Available at: \url{https://www.balls.ie/football/premier-league-playoffs-364654}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```